# Eigenvalues broken for nonsymmetric matrices

Tags: numerics, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

It looks that eigensystem calculation can easily go broken with real nonsymmetric/general complex matrices. Here are two examples with the possibly complex spectra plotted in the complex plane. I'm using Version 12.2.

In both cases, the correct spectrum should have no sawtooth points at all, which can be seen by setting `nN=400`. But often we do need larger sizes. Is there any remedy or am I missing anything?

```
\[Gamma] = 0.1; nN = 550;
mat = DiagonalMatrix[Table[(1 - \[Gamma]), nN - 1], -1] + 
   DiagonalMatrix[Table[(1 + \[Gamma]), nN - 1], 1] +
   DiagonalMatrix[Table[-2, {n, nN}]];
w = Eigenvalues[mat];
ListPlot[ReIm[w], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
t = 1; \[Kappa]1 = 1 - I 0.02; \[Kappa] = 1; \[Gamma] = -0.1;
nN = 500;

offEye1[n_] := DiagonalMatrix[Table[1, n - 1], -1];
tT1 = {{0, (\[Kappa] + t)/2}, {(\[Kappa] - t)/2, 0}};
offEye2[n_] := DiagonalMatrix[Table[1, n - 1], 1];
tT2 = Transpose@tT1;
tAB = {{0, \[Gamma] - \[Kappa]1}, {-\[Gamma] - \[Kappa]1, 0}};
mat0 = ArrayFlatten@ReleaseHold@DiagonalMatrix[Hold /@ Table[tAB, nN]];
mat = mat0 + KroneckerProduct[offEye1[nN], tT1] + 
   KroneckerProduct[offEye2[nN], tT2];

w = Eigenvalues[mat];
ListPlot[ReIm[w], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Same problem in version `13.0` by btw. Although I get different numbers. Could be a problem with precision. The first matrix has large condition number and some small gaps between eigenvalues. The condition number of the second matrix should be okay (the eigenvalues do not touch the origin), but also here the gaps between eigenvalues are tiny.

Comment: Yeah, must be a precision issue: `{w, u} = Eigensystem[mat];Max[Abs[mat . Transpose[u] - Transpose[u] . DiagonalMatrix[w]]]` returns `9.99201*10^-15`. So there is probably no way to compute the eigenvalues accurately in machine precision.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's really about the underlying numerical analysis rather than the software.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I don’t think so. I feel it’s quite a valid question unless things like MKL lapack or Matlab show similar failure, which is partially why we need to investigate here. And if there’s a workaround here it’s rather probably specific to the software.

Comment: `γ = 1/10` instead of 0.1 yields 550 real eigenvalues between -4 and 0, indicating that the problem discussed in the question is due solely to inadequate precision.  Note that the calculation required about 30 minutes on my six-processor PC.

Comment: You raise a fair point. If you or anyone else shows that MKL Lapack does not have this issue then I'll retract my close vote.

Comment: Let me state my position differently. I think it is far more likely that this is intrinsically a conditioning issue rather than a software issue. So I want evidence it is the latter before proceeding down that path. Apologies for my taking a contrarian position in this instance.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thanks for the observation. What could be the controllable way of increasing precision here rather than directly using a fraction?

Comment: Check the documentation for `SetPrecision`.